# The right portion of selected option of HTML Select is turned white

Tags: html, css, select

I have a normal Html Select control with following options:

```
<form action="/target.php">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="cars" id="cars" style="width: 100px; overflow-x: auto;" multiple>
    <option value="volvo">Long select option.</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The first option in the list is a bit longer that the rest. When I select it, I can see the following effect:
[image]

However, as I use the horizontal scrollbar to see the rest of the value it appears something as in the image below:

[image]

The text on the right are all lost (say both foreground and background are while). Now, I click somewhere outside the Select control, the text appears but half of them selected and rest not.

[image]

I tried this with different online html editor and all of them share same behaviour. Is there a way (any css) that I can apply so that once an option is clicked/selected the entire option is selected and not just a portion of it.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is a bit hacky, but it will serve the purpose. You can add the below CSS to make sure the whole item is selected.

```
option:checked {
  width:150px;
}
```

I would also suggest just increasing the width of the selector for a better user experience, if you do that, you will not encounter the above error.